# how to add year or months from current date in groovy?

Tags: date, time, groovy

How to add one year to current date in groovy script?

```
def Format1 = "yyyy-MM-dd"
def today = new Date()
def currentDate = today.format(Format1)
```

Example : 2015-07-29 to 2016-07-29 and 2015-07-29 to 2015-10-29.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [`TimeCategory`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html).

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

def acceptedFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
def today = new Date() + 1
def currentdate = today.format(acceptedFormat)

use(TimeCategory) {
    def oneYear = today + 1.year
    println oneYear

    def ninetyDays = today + 90.days
    println ninetyDays
}
```

More information on how this works can be found in the documentation on [The Groovy Pimp my Library Pattern](http://www.groovy-lang.org/design-patterns.html#_pimp_my_library_pattern). In short, the `Integer` class is enriched in the `use` block, providing it with extra methods that make date manipulation very convenient.

Do note that the `+` (or `plus`) operator already works with regular integers, but the default is then to add one day. (As such, `new Date() + 1` will get you the date in 24 hours)

Comment: Thanks for this.  It's really neat and makes what I want to do easy and quick.

Comment: How to write this without the "use" syntax? Is BaseDuration required?