# NiFi How to Add Months to a Date

Tags: apache-nifi

I know one can add milliseconds to a date for adding days or weeks:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#now

But since months' lengths are different, that will not work. How can I add 6 months to the now() function of NiFi?

Comment: You can try to use this [Groovy TimeCategory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707460/how-to-add-year-or-months-from-current-date-in-groovy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After needing this time and again, I just decided to do it the workaround way without using external scripts which potentially break with upgrades and adds complexity. The below deducts one month.

[image: Set the original date to work from.]

use below for testing dates:

```
${literal('2022-01'):toDate('yyyy-MM')} #202112
${literal('2022-09'):toDate('yyyy-MM')} #202208
${literal('2022-11'):toDate('yyyy-MM')} #202210
```

[image: Split out vars]

[image: Determine new vars]

```
${this_month:equals("1"):ifElse("12",${this_month:minus(1)})}
${this_month:equals("1"):ifElse(${this_year:minus(1)},${this_year})}
```

[image: Set new date]

```
${new_year:append(${new_month:padLeft(2,"0")})}
```

Hope this helps someone somewhere out there.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately doing this reliably (as you've noted) is not really ideal using only Expression Language.

The most reliable method to do this would be:

- UpdateAttribute to set a new attribute with `${now()}`
- ExecuteGroovyScript with a simple piece of Groovy to

  - Get the attribute
  - Use Groovy date/time functions to safely add to the date
  - Set the attribute value

[Cookbook Part 1](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922) covers how to work with FF Attributes.

E.g.

```
flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
my_date = flowFile.getAttribute('my_date')
// Modify your date here
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'my_date', my_date)
```

Comment: Thanks that would certainly work. Fortunately, I just need to deduct 6 months in my case, so I just check if the current month is July (7) or later, then I just deduct 6 from the 202207 to get 202201. If it's 6 or less, I deduct 94. Also thanks for the link to the cookbook!!

Answer (score 1):

this code subtract 60 days from a attribute named 'date_original' and add new attribute with the new date

```
flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
     formatoAccettato = "yyyy-MM-dd"    
     dataOriginale = flowFile.getAttribute('data_originale')
     dataOriginaleDate = Date.parse(formatoAccettato, dataOriginale)
     sottrazione = dataOriginaleDate - 60
     dataSottratta = sottrazione.format(formatoAccettato)
     flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'data_modificata', dataSottratta)
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```