# Add months to a date in groovy

Tags: datetime, groovy

I am trying to add dynamic number of months to a date using groovy. I have tried it using TimeCategory.

I have tried as mentioned in the blog here -
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707460/how-to-add-year-or-months-from-current-date-in-groovy]
However my below code dosent return correct output.
Need help to figure out what's wrong with my code.

My Input - CurrentRunDate = 2022-09-19, additionalmonths = 5

Current output from above code - MM/dd/yyyy5 months

```
import com.sap.it.api.mapping.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

def String AddMonthsToDate(String CurrentRunDate, int additionalmonths){
    def emptydate = "";
    if(CurrentRunDate == "")
    {
        return emptydate;
    }
    else
    {
 
    use(TimeCategory) {
    def currentdate = CurrentRunDate.format("MM/dd/yyyy")
    def addmonths = currentdate + additionalmonths.month
    return addmonths

    }
}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add year or months from current date in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707460/how-to-add-year-or-months-from-current-date-in-groovy)

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I had tried my code on the same lines as mentioned in below blog. However my code dosent give correct output. I am not able to understand the reason why.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707460/how-to-add-year-or-months-from-current-date-in-groovy

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and the other old Java date-time classes from Java 1.0 and 1.1. They are porly deisgned, troublesome and long outdated. Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/time/package-summary.html). (Said not knowing Groovy but knowing Java well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are not converting `CurrentRunDate` into a Date object before using it with TimeCategory. You need to parse the date string, add the months you want, and then convert the Date back into a String to return.

In essence, you'll want something similar to this:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

String addMonthsToDate(String currentRunDate, int additionalMonths) {
    // validate currentRunDate as being present and truthy
    if (!currentRunDate) {
        return ""
    }

    // lets set up our simple date format object for parsing and formating
    def sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")

    // using that formmater let's parse the date string into a date obj
    def parsedDate = sdf.parse(currentRunDate)

    // let's now use that date obj in the TimeCategory body 
    def datePlusOneMonth = use(TimeCategory) { parsedDate + additionalMonths.month }

    // let's convert back to a string 
    return sdf.format(datePlusOneMonth)
}
```

As a test:

```
assert addMonthsToDate("01/01/2000", 1) == "02/01/2000"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response along with comments. It has helped to understand better. 
It worked as expected.